# Script Curl funciona no Windows, mas não no Linux

Tags: linux, windows, libcurl

Tenho um problema com o curl. Quando utilizo este código no apache instalado no Windows 10, funciona sempre. Quando utilizo no Linux, tanto no Ubuntu Server 16.04 quanto no CentOS 7, em ambos dá problema, funciona às vezes, depois de várias tentativas (1 em 5 em média). O que será que está faltando na configuração do Linux? Algo relacionado ao armazenamento de cookes? Estou quase instalando o Windows Server 2012. :(

```
<?php
print buscaPagina();
function buscaPagina()
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    //curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; Media Center PC 4.0)');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);

    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UNRESTRICTED_AUTH,true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://eproc1.tjto.jus.br/eprocV2_prod_1grau/externo_controlador.php?acao=entrar&alt=21');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'selSistema=2&txtUsuario=nomedeusuario&pwdSenha=aquiasenha');
    $retorno = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $retorno;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provavelmente o arquivo `cookie.txt` não pode ser gravado, pois no linux é necessário permissões para gravar arquivos:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
```

Tente criar antes e setar as permissões assim:

```
if (!is_file('cookie.txt')) {
    file_put_contents('cookie.txt', ''); //cria o arquivo se não existir
}

chmod('cookie.txt', 0755); //muda as permissões

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
```

Claro que usei a permissão `0755` supondo que o usuário do Apache ou do PHP seja o mesmo para `www-data`.

No entanto eu recomendo que coloque os dados desse `cookie.txt` em uma pasta fora da past `www` ou da pasta `public_html`, pois os dados em cookies podem ser sensíveis o que pode até ocasionar sequestro de sessão, se alguém navegar no seu site como por exemplo `http://site.com/cookie.txt` ela terá todos dados necessário se você estiver usando alguma autenticação.

Comment: Obrigado! Salvou o Linux. Funcionou!